# How to show xAxis categories up to the each chart in Bar-Highcharts library?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I want to show my categories on the top of each bar chart. like the image.
for this i set bar-chart option as below without any  xAxis categories label.

```
options: {
            title: null,
            chart: {
              type: 'bar'
            },
            colors: ['#9696b2', '#ff058d'],
            xAxis: {
              categories: ['Tokyo', 'Fukuoka', 'Hiroshima', 'Osaka', 'Nagoya'],
              visible: false,
            },
            yAxis: {
              visible: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' '
            },
            plotOptions: {
              bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true
                }
              }
            },
            legend: {
              enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
series: [{
              name: 'Compliant',
              data: [1300, 1121, 1700, 1121, 700]
            }, {
              name: 'Non-Compliant',
              data: [60, 30, 50, 20, 0]
            }]
          }
```

[image: what i want]
[image: what i have]

how can i make this one with stacked horizontal bars?
[image: the new one]

Answer (score 1):

You can align labels to left and position them by `x` and `y` properties:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 0,
        y: -24
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4767/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.labels

Comment: that works, tnx, you know with which option i can make the third image with stacked horizontal bars?

Comment: Hi @samira, Please create a new SO question with `highcharts` tag.